# What are true and false operators in C#?

Tags: c#, operators

What is the purpose and effect of the `true` and `false` **operators** in C#?  The [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahhcxk2(VS.71).aspx) on these is hopelessly non-explanatory.

Comment: What if both 'true' and 'false' operators return true?

Comment: @alex: then expect interesting result.

Comment: @alex, I don't think the false operation is actually used when determining true/false when being evaluated. I'll see if I can confirm.

Comment: Never mind, it is called when determining if it can short circuit &&.

Comment: @Samuel, it might also be used elsewhere to optimise calling the 'not' operator on the result of the 'true' operator.  This is, however, just a guess.

Comment: @ProfK (to your comment) No, `operator false` is not used in that case. The only use is short-circuit `&&`. But you can overload `operator !` if you want to be able to call "not" on your type.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The true and false operators can be overloaded, to allow a class to represent its own state as true or false, for example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    //...
    public static bool operator true(MyClass op)
    {
        // Evaluation code...
    }

    public static bool operator false(MyClass op)
    {
        // Evaluation code...
    }
}
```

And  you will be able to use the operator in boolean expressions:

```
MyClass test = new MyClass(4, 3);
if (test)
    Console.WriteLine("Something true");
else
    Console.WriteLine("Something false");

string text = test ? "Returned true" : "Returned false";
```

Comment: What if both 'true' and 'false' operators return true?

Comment: @alex, in the absence of checks for false in the above example from CMS, I would expect nothing unseemly.

Comment: @alex This example is only relevant for `operator true`. It is only `operator true` which is considered if you use `MyClass` above inside an `if`, `while` etc., or with the `? :` ternary operator. The only situation where `operator false` matters, seems to be if `MyClass` also overloads the `operator &`, in a suitable way. So you can say `MyClass conj = GetMyClass1() & GetMyClass2();`. Then with `operator false` you can short-circuit and say `MyClass conj = GetMyClass1() && GetMyClass2();`, using `&&` instead of `&`. That will only evaluate the second operand if the first one is not "false".

Answer (score 15):

**You would overload the `true` or `false` operators if you were defining a specialized boolean value.** This is not typically needed, however, which is why they don't seem useful. For example, in a fuzzy-logic boolean class, you might have something like this:

```
// Represents a boolean that can store truth values in a range from [0, 1], with
//   a value of one indicating complete metaphysical certitude and a value of
//   zero indicating complete impossibility.
public class FuzzyBoolean {
// ...
   public static bool operator true(FuzzyBoolean fb) {
      return fb.TruthValue > 0;
   }

   public static bool operator false(FuzzyBoolean fb) {
      return fb.TruthValue == 0;
   }
// ...
}
```

Note that if you overload `true`, you must also overload `false` (and vice versa).

Of course, there are also the `true` and `false` *literals*, the two literal values you can assign to a boolean instance. Don't confuse these with the operators mentioned above. A more substantial example of how you'd use this, involving booleans in a database, is given in the MSDN docs [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664483%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: This seems like a very contrived example. I would see the use of something like this for objects having an OK and a bad state - say a file object could return true if it was in a readable state, allowing one to write a C like 'if (file) { /* do something */ }` construct.

Comment: @Ori: IMO, that's a terrible idea. A file is not a boolean and should not be used as such. If you want to check if it's in a good state, that should be a boolean method: "file.IsValid()" or something similar.

Comment: Neither are FuzzyBooleans, whatever you name them. Using various things as booleans is idiomatic in certain languages. It might not be in C#, but given the extensive facilities to support casting to boolean I suspect that something like that was intended, rather than the ability to define

Comment: a new boolean type, which I suspect would be pretty rare.

Comment: My point was that the distance between a FuzzyBoolean and a boolean is much tinier than the distance between the distance between a file and a boolean. C# doesn't prevent you from making implicit conversions to your heart's content; I'm just saying I don't think it's necessarily a great idea.

Comment: And I don't necessarily disagree. This is a perfectly acceptable idiom in C, C++ and Python. I don't know enough about C# to tell you whether it would be a good idea or not to do this in C#. I just don't think that the argument "a file is not a boolean" has any merit on its own.

Comment: To really be argumentative, I could say that an int is not a boolean, and neither is a bit or a voltage level in a circuit. A boolean is a narrowly defined mathematical construct, and its use in a computer language is subject to the whim of the language's designer. As such, what's considered

Comment: acceptable or not is driven by practical considerations, one of which being readability. Easily casting arbitrary classes to boolean can enhance or hinder readability. We must use good judgment. Think of something like a reference class, which lets you delegate operations to an instance running on

Comment: another machine - it's rather like a pointer. It might be reasonable to expect people to know what this means: "if (myRef) { myRef.DoSomething(); }". 

OK, this is getting silly.

Comment: @Ori: In C# I would say the general consensus is that types stand alone. Unless you have a pretty good reason for an implicit conversion, it's usually considered bad form to supply one. This would make a good SO question, too: "When is it okay to have an implicit conversion?"

Comment: By the way, I found the FuzzyBoolean example contrived because in order to implement fuzzy logic using them you'd have to overload the && and || operators, which I believe you can't, and the transformation from [0,1] to { false, true } is very lossy.

Comment: @Ori: If it weren't lossy, then you could have just used a boolean method anyway. In this case it's lossy because, well, that's the point, to reduce the truth value to a binary state. That's like saying "% is lossy because it only gives you the remainder". But that's the part you care about. :)

Comment: We really should make a blog post out of this or something. It's a good discussion. And I wish SO had private messaging!

Comment: The problem with a lossy transformation in this case is that a fuzzy truth value of, say, 0.5, has a well defined meaning withing the axioms of fuzzy logic (however you define that.) Squashing that to true or false isn't very useful, while overloading the logic operators for fuzzy values would be.

Comment: As for private messages, I'm sure you could figure out my email address if you worked at it a bit.

Answer (score 5):

See the referenced example in the article

[C# Language Specification -- Database boolean type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664483(VS.71).aspx)

Essentially these operators allow an instance of a type to be used in boolean conditional logic such as `&&` and `||`.

Answer (score 3):

They allow you to overload them using the operator overloading syntax so that a type you define can be interpreted as a boolean.

Answer (score 3):

Prior to C# 2.0, the true and false operators were used to create user-defined nullable value types that were compatible with types such as SqlBool. However, the language now provides built-in support for nullable value types, and whenever possible you should use those instead of overloading the true and false operators. For more information.With nullable Booleans, the expression a != b is not necessarily equal to !(a == b) because one or both of the values might be null. You need to overload both the true and false operators separately to correctly identify the null values in the expression. The following example shows how to overload and use the true and false operators.

Answer (score 0):

The allow you to use a custom type as a part of logic operations; For example, as part of an if or while statement.